# dynamic and static optimization of parameters or sensitivity analysis using OpenModelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

Is Optimica the only reasonable approach or does there exist more straight forward ways ? I have used OMOPtim in earlier versions but it doesn't work reliably and does not provide one shot optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

PyFMI + Assimulo (CVodes) could do sensitivity analysis

Answer (score 1):

OpenModelica has also a method based on IDAS. See the [OpenModelica UserGuide](https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/parametersensitivity.html).